# Easiest way to handle one checkbox with multiple options (submit buttons)

Tags: php, submit

I am developing a backend-Adminpanel, from where I would like to make different commands for users. I would like to list every registered user, and some buttons like: remove, changePassword, makeAdmin etc., but how do I do that with one checkbox? I'd need a form-element for every "command" right? But that means, I would need a checkbox/radiobutton for every task.. and that wouldn't be nice. How could I program the userlist?

My code:

```
        <div id="margin-down" class="col s12 m6 offset-m3 green darken-3 rund">
            <h3 class="white-text center-align">Users</h3><br>
            <form action="" method="Post">
                <ul id="Liste" class="collection z-depth-1">
                    <?php
        try {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=todo;host=localhost",
                    "root",
                    "");
        }catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Fehler: " . htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage());
                exit();
                    }
        if(isset($_COOKIE["admin"])){                
        $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user");
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                echo "<li class='collection-item blue-grey lighten-5 dick'>" . $row["username"] . "<label class='right'><input type='checkbox' name='entry[]'  value=''> <span>Löschen</span></label> </li>" ;
            }

}?>
                </ul>

            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why do you even need a checkbox / radio button?

Comment: @JonStirling To pick the user, where I want to do the action.

Like there are 10 users in the list, and I want to delete one of them. I'd need to check the radiobutton, for that the submit-button knows, that it's that user.

Comment: You shoud at least give us a minimum of code.

Comment: @Jimmy Why not just use links like everyone else? The link would contain the ID of the user you're wanting to perform the action on, which you'd inject using your PHP.

Comment: Do you know how to show list of user ? @jimmy

Comment: My Userlist looks like: https://gyazo.com/fffe8c469e001f2a54ab970f3b8baef8

Comment: @KubiRoazhon Edited the question.

Comment: @JonStirling Links? How would I do that? Like what would I insert in the href attribute?

Comment: That's up to you. You could add it much the same way as you're doing with the echo of the li tag.

Comment: @JonStirling Sure, I could add links, which refer to "delete.php" "changepassword.php" etc. but on these php-files, how can I identify, which user-removeLink was clicked? There's no $_POST or a value, which I could add dynamicly to the anchor-tag..

Comment: You can use this kind of code `<a href="page1.php?uid=12" class="button"> Remove </a> <a href="page2.php?uid=12" class="button"> changePassword </a> <a href="page3.php?uid=12" class="button"> makeAdmin  </a>` where page.php will be your page on which you want to do process. In uid you have to add ID using php code. you can uid on other page using $_GET or anything..   Hope you get what i'm trying to say

Comment: @KhooshbuPatel Ahh I see, and on the page (page1.php for example) I guess I can grab the uid with GET? How would I identifer the id itself? if I type href="page2.php?uid=12    , how can the GET variable, find the 12?

Comment: `$_GET['uid'];`

Comment: Okay, that seems pretty easy. I will definitely try this way!

Comment: It works fantastic! That makes me so motivated for some reason. I never dealt with $_GET because everyone says, it's unsecure.. but I guess, if the adminpanel can only be entered with a cookie (which gets only set if the DB says, the user is admin) it could be secure enough.

Comment: $_GET is only insecure if you don't validate and sanitise the values that are being input. The same applies for $_POST which also isn't secure if you just accept the values as is.